# is it possible to use useInterceptor on exception filter on nestJs?

Tags: filter, nestjs, interceptor

I tried to use an interceptor on a filter as

```
@Catch(ValidationException)
@UseInterceptor(ExceptionInterceptor)
export class ValidationExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor() {}
  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const context = host.switchToHttp();
    const request = context.getRequest<Request>();
    const response = context.getResponse<Response>();
    
    return {message: 'custome error occured'};
  }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

No. Interceptors, and the other Nest enhancers, only work on controllers, gateways, and resolvers, i.e. where the request comes into server. This is by design to keep the mental complexity of the server low, and to keep request times down.